# How to add adsense in unity webplayer games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, unity-web-player

I want to know that how can i add Google adsense in unity games for web-player only. I know for mobile we use admob .

I see games on kongregate.com and several other sites that they have few seconds timer and in this time they show their Google ads in game iframe .

Now how can i do the same in unity ?

Comment: Looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having a form of ads in a unity game is indeed possible [GameAdTrading](http://www.gameadtrading.com/?lang=en) is one of the few, if not only providers of this service. They offer ads for mobile, web and standalone players.

adding actual AdSense is not possible as can be read in this [adsense topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/CyBKeb3qh8w)  Where the support obviously states that another monetizing option should be found.

Theoratically you also should be able to inject the ad code into the website using Application.ExternaEval(). Do keep in mind that this might be penalized by google, if it does not require special permissions to begin with